# Are double and double? interchangeable?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know whether a `double` is implicitly cast to `double?` (`Nullable` type)

EDIT: What exactly is going on here?

```cs
double d = 5;

double? d2 = d as double?
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: Why no write "double? d = 1.0;" in you IDE and see if it compiles?

Comment: From §6.1.4 (Implicit nullable conversions): ". For each of the predefined implicit identity and numeric conversions that convert from a non-nullable value type `S` to a non-nullable value type `T`, the following implicit nullable conversions exist: [...] • An implicit conversion from `S` to `T?`." With `double` playing the role of `S` and `double` playing the role of `T` (both non-nullable) and noting that there is an implicit conversion from `double` (`S`) to `double` (`T`) there is, by the above clause, an implicit conversion from `double` (`S`) to `double?` (`T?`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What exactly is going on here?

```
double d = 5;
double? d2 = d as double?;
```

Well, let's go through it.

In the first line, you declare a local variable named d of type double. You assign the constant integer 5 to it. The compiler converts the constant integer 5 to the double 5.0 for you and generates code which assigns the value to the local.

In the second line you declare a local variable named d2 of type double?.

The expression "d as double?" is equivalent to "d is double? ? (double?)d : (double?) null" except of course that "d" is only evaluated once.

The portion of that which reads "d is double?" is evaluated as true, because d is known to be of type double. (When asked "x is y", if x is of a non-nullable type and y is the corresponding nullable type then the result is always true.)

The compiler knows this and therefore discards the alternative "(double?) null".  Therefore the code generated is as though you'd said

```
double? d2 = (double?)d;
```

This is generated by calling the constructor of double?, passing in d as the argument to the constructor, and a reference to local variable d2 as "this".  So this becomes essentially:

```
double? d2 = new Nullable<double>(d);
```

That is *exactly* what is going on there. Does that all make sense?

Comment: Eric : The compiler does not complain when you do this double? d2 = d;?   Is it normal for implicit casts to call a constructor?

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw: It is for conversions that involve value types. You convert an int to a double, we construct you a new double. Of course the "constructor" for a double is a single instruction in IL, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 19):

They're not interchangeable as per your title.

There is an *implicit* conversion from `double` to `double?`.

There is an *explicit* conversion from `double?` to `double`.

The same is true for all nullable value types: there's an implicit conversion from `T` to `Nullable<T>`, and an explicit one from `Nullable<T>` to `T`.

Interestingly, although `Nullable<T>` does provide those conversions as user-defined conversions in the normal way, the MS C# compiler doesn't use those - it calls the `Nullable<T>(T value)` constructor for the implicit conversion, and uses the `Value` property directly for the explicit conversion the other way round.

Comment: @Perpetualcoder: It's 11:50pm in the UK - I'm about to go to bed :)

Comment: @Jon: Raking up a few hundred rep points before you hit the bed :)

Comment: @Perpetualcoder: Not with the rep cap in place, no. No points for this answer... (until after midnight, anyway).

Comment: But the old Chinese man at the shop said "Keep him away from bright light and water, and whatever you do, don't give Skeet rep after midnight."

Comment: @Eric: I very nearly tweeted something similar last night, but couldn't get the quote quite right...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `double` is implicitly cast to `double?`. E.g. if `d` is a `double` then `double? nullableD = d;` is fine.

Although `double?` is not implicitly cast to `double`. In this case you should use `double d = nullableD.Value;`

Comment: You can also use a cast, but it will throw an exception if it's null.

Comment: you should only use nullableD.value after checking that nullableD is not null of course.

Comment: @Paul: Unless you're happy with the exception, in which case it's fine to just use Value.

Comment: @Brian - yes, that is true, btw nullableD.Value will also throw an exception if null so same behaviour
@Paul - yes, that is correct

Answer (score 4):

You can it as follows

```
    double? d;
    d = 12.00    
    double d2 = (double)d;
```

be careful before you cast as double? could be null; better to do this check

---

```
    if(d.HasValue)
    { double d2 = (double)d; }
```

Comment: It's only better to manually check if the value can be null without it being due to a bug or some other condition which should cause an exception.